# Why is it illegal to annoy someone via electronic communication in Massachusetts?

Tags: massachusetts, harassment

According to Massachusetts State General Law, Chapter 269, Section 14A, it is illegal to send repeated communications to someone with the intent to annoy the person, punishable be 3 months in a correctional facility and up to $500 in fines. Why would annoyance be illegal only if the communication method is electronic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annoyance may be illegal even if it's not done electronically; it just wouldn't be prosecuted under this specific law.

Under [Chapter 269, § 14A](https://malegislature.gov/Laws/GeneralLaws/PartIV/TitleI/Chapter269/Section14A), it is illegal when a person:

> contacts another person by electronic communication ... for the sole purpose of harassing, annoying or molesting the person or the person’s family.

That same law also makes it illegal when a person:

> contacts a person repeatedly by electronic communication and uses indecent or obscene language to the person.

But Massachusetts prohibits annoyance in several other contexts, as well:

- [Chapter 265 § 43](https://malegislature.gov/Laws/GeneralLaws/PartIV/TitleI/Chapter265/Section43), the anti-stalking statute, deals with engaging in "a knowing pattern of conduct or series of acts over a period of time directed at a specific person which seriously alarms or **annoys** that person and would cause a reasonable person to suffer substantial emotional distress."
- [Chapter 266 § 37E](https://malegislature.gov/Laws/GeneralLaws/PartIV/TitleI/Chapter266/Section37E), the identity-theft statute, covers activity that "seriously alarms or **annoys** such person or persons and would cause a reasonable person to suffer substantial emotional distress."
- [Chapter 268 § 13B](https://malegislature.gov/Laws/GeneralLaws/PartIV/TitleI/Chapter268/Section13B) uses the same language in prohibiting harassment of jurors, witnesses, etc.
- [Chapter 272 § 43](https://malegislature.gov/Laws/GeneralLaws/PartIV/TitleI/Chapter272/Section43), penalizes "whoever, in or upon a railroad carriage, steamboat or other public conveyance, is disorderly, or disturbs or **annoys** travelers in or upon the same by profane, obscene or indecent language, or by indecent behavior."
- [Chapter 272 § 53](https://malegislature.gov/Laws/GeneralLaws/PartIV/TitleI/Chapter272/Section53) penalizes "persons who with offensive and disorderly acts or language accost or **annoy** another person."

Note that these kinds of laws are often interpreted very broadly, so even though a law may exist purporting to govern annoyance, it may still be suspect under First Amendment analysis. An somewhat similar annoyance law in New Jersey was just [pared back by the Supreme Court](http://reason.com/volokh/2017/12/19/can-repeated-speech-be-criminalized-just) there last year.